# how to embed widget using script tag in react application

Tags: reactjs, widget, react-widgets

I am trying to add a third party widget in my react app but I am not sure how to do. The widget owner wants me to add it via script tag and I tried it in plan HTML file and it is working there. but with my react app It is not. I tried adding the script tag in my index.html, but it is not showing up in the component where I want to display it.

This is the script tag I am trying to implement

```
<script 
 data-currency="EUR" 
 data-lang="en" 
 data-from="toronto_on_ca" 
 src="https://widgets.kiwi.com/scripts/widget-search-iframe.js">
</script>
```